# How can I get list of embedded and referenced fonts via abcpdf?

Tags: c#, pdf, abcpdf

I can embed fonts, add (reference) fonts, set a current font, but that seems to be it.

How can I get a list of embedded and referenced fonts in a pdf file via abcpdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think ABCpdf provides a way to get a list of the fonts that are in an already existing PDF. There just isn't any implementation of that. You'd need to dig through the `ObjectSoup` with knowledge of PDF internals.

There are other tools that can list the fonts in a PDF, for example [pdffonts](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdffonts1.html) from the `xpdf` package.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your scenario but I've had luck using this with ABCPdf 10.

```
public IEnumerable<string> EmbeddedFonts
{
    get
    {
        return doc.ObjectSoup.Catalog.GetFonts()
          .Select(x => x.BaseFont).Where(x => 
             !x.StartsWith("Helvetica") && 
             !x.StartsWith("Times") && 
             !x.StartsWith("Zapf")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [FontObject](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source/6-abcpdf.objects/fontobject/default.htm) class. For example:

```
List<string> embeddedFonts = new List<string>();
List<string> referencedFonts = new List<string>();
FontObject[] fonts = doc.ObjectSoup.Catalog.GetFonts();
foreach (FontObject font in fonts) {
    if (font.EmbeddedFont == null) {
    referencedFonts.Add(font.BaseFont);
    } else {
    embeddedFonts.Add(font.BaseFont);
    }
}
```